# How can I make sure that the user has opened the link from React Native app?

Tags: react-native

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (appState === "background") {
      someFunction(data.id);
    }
  }, [appState, data.id]);
```

Hi! Need help. I'm developing an app on React Native. And the question is: if the user opens the link, a modal window pops up in the application, where can he choose the browser in which to open the link. But he may not open it and come back. How can I make sure that the user actually follows the link?

Answer (score 0):

The only feedback you have when opening a link from your React Native app is the promise result.

Method: [Linking.openUrl](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#openurl)
Return: `Promise<any>`

> The method returns a Promise object. If the user confirms the open dialog or the url automatically opens, the promise is resolved. If the user cancels the open dialog or there are no registered applications for the url, the promise is rejected.

Example:

```
export const openUrl = (url, type) => {
    Linking.openURL(url)
        .then(() => {
            // link open
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // failed to open the link (no app or?)
        })
}
```